# Getting 403 error while running search api using twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Hi i am trying to collect data from twitter search Api using Twitter4j. Every thing is working fine but after certain no. of calls to the Api it is throwing the following error.

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Missing or invalid url parameter
code - 195
```

Using `thread.sleep` i am calling Api every 1 min. so at the max it can have 60 calls. But the limit is 350 with authentication, then also i am getting this error.

Please help me out i am very new to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you sending in the DM. From now on it seems that if your message contains an URL the DM will be rejected:

https://support.twitter.com/articles/14606-posting-or-deleting-direct-messages